# pgAdmin query tool stays frozen even after query is over

Tags: pgadmin

I am running postgresql 9.6 in my windows 7 laptop. Nobody else connects to the database. I ran an insert SQL in Query Tool of Pgadmin4. The query got over after 20 minutes or so. The records got inserted & the state in pg_stat_activity went from active to idle which I checked by opening the other query tool window. But the original window in which the query was run continued to be frozen with message

> "waiting for the query execution to complete"

How can I fix this problem. I did some research. Does it have something to do with TCP/IP connection getting broken as mentioned in below links

[Link 1](https://superuser.com/questions/729034/any-way-to-keep-connection-alive-in-pgadmin-without-setting-it-on-the-server)

and

[Link 2](https://www.pgadmin.org/support/faq.php) (under Connection to database dropped)

Answer (score 11):

Restart pgadmin and try the query again.

as of 2018 pgadmin seems to handle connection timeouts really badly, so you will often need to restart the entire pgadmin appliction after a period of not using it, and then go through the process of expanding the tree again to get right down to the table you were working with.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a solution but got a work around. The problem was that after query execution it was running the autovacuum and then even after it got over, pgadmin was staying frozen. I disabled autovacuum in the config file and it started working fine. Not sure if this will have any impact on performance or anything else. Will see.

Comment: Autovacuum is important without it you will have to do additional DB maintenance. See this for more info: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/routine-vacuuming.html

Answer (score -1):

Do not use "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" as host. Use your IP address instead. That solved the issue on my side.