# Update statement causes unusual behaviour

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgresql database, with a table created with the following SQL:

```sql
create table aisle_slots (
    id          serial not null primary key,
    occupied    boolean,
    aisle_index int,
    x           real,
    y           real,
    rot         real
);
```

Insert and delete queries work fine on this table.

Every type of query works fine on every other table in the database.

However, running the following update query causes unusual behaviour:

```sql
update aisle_slots
set occupied = true
where id = 3
```

Running this in pgAdmin locks up the application (it gets stuck on "waiting for the query execution to complete..."). Running it in Psycopg2 returns instantly, but doesn't actually make any changes in the database. Neither causes any error messages or log output.

`select version()` output:

```
PostgreSQL 9.6.13 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16), 64-bit
```

What could be going on here?

Comment: How large is this table, and what other process(es) might be using it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Very small, about 7 rows. AFAIK no other processes using it, the application that would normally use it is off when I use pgAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164464/12550116)

> Restart pgadmin and try the query again.
>
> pgadmin seems to handle connection timeouts really badly, so you will
>   often need to restart the entire pgadmin appliction after a period of
>   not using it, and then go through the process of expanding the tree
>   again to get right down to the table you were working with.
>
> It does make me wonder whether the authors of pgadmin actually eat
>   their own dogfood, as it's quite painful to use day-to-day compared to
>   say SQL Server's Management Studio

.